# Python: List and map functions arent working properly

Tags: python

I am having some troubles with working with given data. The task is simple, all I need to do is to swap the first maximum element with the last one in the list. Input data is just a sequence of numbers, separated by the space. If I use map to convert every number from str to int it fails tests, but the error code doesn't show up, so I don't have any idea how to fix this.

The code is written on Python 3.6.3. I tried to convert str numbers to int in many ways, but every try failed 3rd test except the one when I don't convert numbers at all.

```
def max_elem_to_last(array, start_index, end_index):

    maximum = max(array[start_index:end_index])
    index_max = array.index(maximum)
    array[end_index - 1], array[index_max] = array[index_max], array[end_index - 1]


with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

length = int(data[0].replace('\n', '')[0])
dataIO = data[1].replace('\n', '').split()
a = list(map(int, dataIO))

max_elem_to_last(a, 0, length)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for elem in a:
        file.write(str(elem) + ' ')
```

The example of given data:

```
5
1 2 5 4 3
```

Answer:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Also, `input.txt` always contains correct data, so there can't be converting some text to an integer.

Comment: `data.read()`, `a = list(map(int, data.split()))` could possibly work, an example of your data format is needed, though.

Comment: What, *exactly* doesn't work? You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Without input example it is hard to comment. It is a possibility somewhere you are trying to convert string like `'a'` to integer

Comment: You might need to check to see if the sting is a valid integer before converting it. In your map function, you will need to pass in a lambda that does this check and returns the converted integer. However, this might not be desirable as you need to decide what to return if it is not a valid integer. List comprehension might be more suitable as you can skip over invalid integers.

Comment: Here is the example of input data: `5\n 1 2 5 3 4` and my code does well with this particular example. But for some reason this code fails the first test but I cannot check the exact sample in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, I forgot to deal with the case, where the length of an array is 0.